# Comparing fields of object store in arraylist using iterator

Tags: java, if-statement, arraylist, iterator, return-value

I am passing an integer value address to this function. This integer value is contained by one of the object stored in Arraylist "instrHolder". Now I want to first find out which object contains this value and return the entire object of type "Instruction". Here is what I am trying -

```
private static Instruction getInstruction( int address) {
    Iterator<Instruction> iterator = instrHolder.iterator();
    while(iterator.hasNext()){
        if(/*condition need to know*/)
        return /*need to know*/;
    }
}
```

How should I write the if condition and what should be my return statement? Please help me out?

Comment: What should happen if the condition is never true ? Throw an exception ? Return a default value ?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

`iterator.next()` will give you the current instance of the `List`. You should check your condition on that instance and return it if the condition is satisfied :

```
private static Instruction getInstruction(int address) {
    Iterator<Instruction> iterator = instrHolder.iterator();
    while (iterator.hasNext()) {
        Instruction current = iterator.next();
        if (current.getSomeProperty().equals(someValue))
            return current;
    }
    return null;
}
```

As hinted by Spotted, you should decide what to return if no element of your list matches the condition. I chose to return null in this case.

Comment: From your experience, how would you handle the case when no element in the collection matches the condition ?

Comment: @Spotted That depends on the use case. If it is a valid scenario for no element of the collection to match the condition, you can return null. Otherwise you can throw an exception. Thanks for your comment.

Answer (score 2):

You can use `iterator.next()` and because you wanted to compare `integer` `address`, you can refer below code:

```
while (iterator.hasNext()) {
            Instruction instruction = iterator.next();//Get single instruction
            //Get getAddress() from instruction object
            if (instruction.getAddressValue() == address) {
                return instruction;
            }
        }
```

Comment: From your experience, how would you handle the case when no element in the collection matches the condition ?

Answer (score 1):

Since `instrHolder` is an `ArrayList`, don't bother with an `Iterator`. Rather use `Stream` and `Optional`. Also, in your code the behavior is not specified in case no element matches the `address`. In the code below it throws an exception, but it can also return a default value (with `orElse()`).

```
private static Instruction getInstruction( int address) {
    return instrHolder.stream()
                      .filter(i -> i.getAddress() == address)
                      .findFirst()
                      .orElseThrow(NoSuchElementException::new);
}
```